# I need help to make an apa style bibliography in LaTeX

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

Im using Spanish `babel` and I need to do an `apa` style bibliography in Spanish but when I use `apa` style bibliography it just shows the word `referencias` (references) but doesn't show the references I have written on a `.bib` file. I appreciate any help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Are you compiling with pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

With BibLaTeX, there is a `biblatex-apa` style which works out of the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}
\addbibresource{mybibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Run `pdflatex + biber + pdflatex`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have found to put apa like bibliography in spanish is by using the [`apacite`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite) package.

I use something like:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

and compile `pdflatex` + `bibtex` + `pdflatex`

By default in the bibliography only appear the references that are cited in the text. If you want there the entire list of references you must add `\nocite{*}`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```